# Active Directory update script from a T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to query data from a SQL Server database, and use that data to update Active Directory Manager and Department fields. I am not sure where I am going wrong. So far this works without issue:

```
Import-Module SqlServer
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 

$logfile = "C:\working\ADimportlog.txt"

$query = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT a.EmployeeNumber,a.UserId,b.UserID as SupervisorUserID, a.NickName + ' ' + a.lastname as Name, a.StoreNumber as DepartmentNumber, c.StoreName as DepartmentName 
FROM CommonData..CompiledNonSensitiveEmployeeInformation a 
JOIN CommonData..CompiledNonSensitiveEmployeeInformation b ON a.SupervisorEmployeeNumber = b.EmployeeNumber 
JOIN CommonData..CompiledStoreData c ON a.StoreNumber = c.StoreNumber
WHERE SUBSTRING(a.EmploymentStatus, 1, 1) = 'A' AND LEN(a.UserId) > 3 AND c.LocationType = 4
ORDER BY EmployeeNumber" -Database Data -ServerInstance data 

foreach ($item in $query) {
    $name = $item.userid
    $dept = $item.departmentname
    $manager = $item.SupervisorUserID
    $aduser = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=IT,OU=Users,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com" -Filter {samaccountname -eq $name} -Properties *

    foreach ($user in $aduser) {
        $ADManager =  (Get-ADUser (Get-ADUser $user -Properties manager).manager).samaccountName
        if ($ADManager -eq $manager)
        {Add-Content $logfile "User $($user.name) ,No Manager Changes needed."} 
        else 
        {$user | Set-ADUser -Manager $manager -ErrorAction Ignore -WhatIf; Add-Content $logfile "User $($user.name) MANAGER UPDATED."}
    }
```

When I add the update department Syntax, I do not get the expected results. Random AD users get departments updated that do not need updating. It is all over the board, not sure where I am going wrong here:

```
foreach ($user in $aduser) {
        $ADdept = $user.Department

        if ($dept -eq $ADdept)
        {Add-Content $logfile "User $($user.name) ,No Department Changes needed."} 
        else 
        {$user | Set-ADUser -Department $dept -ErrorAction Ignore -WhatIf; Add-Content $logfile "User $($user.name) DEPARTMENT UPDATED."}
    }
```

I am sure it is something obvious that I am missing, I am hoping someone here can point it out, thanks

Comment: Are you able to take a look at the data that you are querying? e.g. `$query | Export-Csv users.csv` look for a user where the department is wrong? i.e. let's narrow it down if the issue is with the data or the update. Personally, the update "looks" ok.

Comment: yes, I looked at it again this morning and seems to be a data issue, i found the discrepancy this morning.